# Calculate the value of sales for the last 4 quarters full advantage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the value of sales for the last 4 quarters full advantage of SQL Server. For example from 2014-10-01 to 2015-09-30 counting today. The procedure has to be repeated every quarter for the last four quarters.

I know that I can provide the date of the but do would be to create an expression that showed the last 4 quarters? I calculate Quarter with `DatePart(quarter(convert (datetime, @ date - 36, 163.105)))`, but how to do it for the last 4?

Sorry for my English

Comment: Do you want start and end dates as a result? And it is unclear what are you asking for. Show what you want as a result if you would run the script today.

Comment: I have a database list of sales invoices to the value of the sale and the date of sale . I need the sum of the values ​​of the last 4 quarters full . The calculation is performed cyclically every quarter. You can return date

Comment: The question was about what is the last 4 quarters? Can you just write startdate and lastdate of those quarters for today?

Comment: For example, generating a report today would show sales for 1,2,3 quarters of 2015 and quarter 4 2014 . Ie the value for the last 4 full quarters .

Comment: I do not want to enter startdate and lastdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example how you can achieve this:

```
;WITH quarters AS(SELECT DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,0,GETDATE())), 0) AS sd, DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS ed
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-1,GETDATE())), 0) AS sd, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,0,GETDATE())), 0) AS ed
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-2,GETDATE())), 0) AS sd, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-1,GETDATE())), 0) AS ed
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-3,GETDATE())), 0) AS sd, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-2,GETDATE())), 0) AS ed
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-4,GETDATE())), 0) AS sd, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-3,GETDATE())), 0) AS ed),
finalQuarters AS(SELECT TOP 4 * FROM quarters WHERE DAY(ed) = 1
                 ORDER BY ed DESC)
SELECT q.sd, 
       q.ed, 
      SUM(s.Amount) AS Amount 
FROM finalQuarters q
JOIN Sales s ON s.SaleDate >= q.sd AND s.SaleDate < q.ed
GROUP BY q.sd, q.ed
```

The idea is to get last 5 quarters in first cte and filter only last ones where the enddate's day part equals 1. It is something difficult to explain. Just play with `select * from finalQuarters--or quarters` and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

SELECT SUM(sallary), DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,DATEADD(qq,-4,my_date)), 0)
 FROM my_table
where my_date >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,DATEADD(qq,-4,getdate())), 0)
GROUP BY DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,DATEADD(qq,-4,my_date)), 0)